# Flutter testing: static method I need to mock inside code

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, static

I want to test a method that is responsible for a button tap (let's call it `onButtonTap()`), one of the first methods is a call to static method from utils file, that returns true of false, depending on set android/ios permissions (or allows user to change permissions by showing dialog that can open application settings). Let's call it `checkOrRequestPermissions()`. This makes everything behind that code untestable, as I don't know how to test it - I can't mock this class because:

- It's not injected anywhere - it's inside utils file
- It's static

So for better visualization lets go like this:

Code from file I want to test:

```
Future<void> onButtonTap(BuildContext context) async {
   bool isGranted = await PermissionsUtil.checkOrRequestPermissions([some_args]);
   // CODE_A - some code I want to test
}
```

Code inside PermissionsUtil:

```
class PermissionsUtil{
    static Future<bool> checkOrRequestPermissions([some_args]){
        // code for permissions
    }
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there any way I could mock `checkOrRequestPermissions()` to simply return given value?
2. How could I make this code testable?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/69042013/.  At best you can try wrapping it so that all of your own calls can go through the wrapper and use a fake implementation.  Otherwise complain to the author about lack of testability.

Comment: Yes, @jamesdlin tell true. You need wrap the code inside a no static method. for unit test, you need to use mockito when method and mock your result.